# Error when i "make" opencv2-4-9 in raspberry pi 3 model B v1.2

Tags: linux, opencv, opengl, raspberry-pi3

I want to install opencv2.4.9 on raspberry pi 3 model b v1.2 2015. I follow [this page](http://www.samontab.com/web/2014/06/installing-opencv-2-4-9-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts/)  to install opencv. when i "make" opencv, i see these errors :

```
[  1%] Built target opencv_ts_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_ts
[  1%] Built target opencv_core_pch_dephelp
[  1%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_core
[  3%] Built target opencv_core
[  3%] Built target opencv_imgproc_pch_dephelp
[  3%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_imgproc
[  5%] Built target opencv_imgproc
[  6%] Built target opencv_highgui_pch_dephelp
[  6%] Built target pch_Generate_opencv_highgui
[  6%] Building CXX object modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o
In file included from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:32:0,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:59:
/usr/include/GL/gl.h:134:17: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef double GLdouble’
 typedef double  GLdouble; /* double precision float */
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5:0,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.h:46,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:47:
/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:85:17: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef GLfloat GLdouble’
 typedef GLfloat GLdouble;
                 ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:32,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:59:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:468:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef std::ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr’
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLsizeiptr;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:79:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.h:46,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:47:
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:69:25: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr’
 typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr;
                         ^
In file included from /usr/include/GL/gl.h:2055:0,
                 from /usr/include/GL/glx.h:32,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:59:
/usr/include/GL/glext.h:469:19: error: conflicting declaration ‘typedef std::ptrdiff_t GLintptr’
 typedef ptrdiff_t GLintptr;
                   ^
In file included from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/qgl.h:79:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/QtOpenGL:5,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.h:46,
                 from /home/nao/Desktop/opencv-2.4.9/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:47:
/usr/include/GLES2/gl2.h:70:26: note: previous declaration as ‘typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr’
 typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr;
                          ^
modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/build.make:227: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/src/window_QT.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1868: recipe for target 'modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/highgui/CMakeFiles/opencv_highgui.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:149: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I see [this page](http://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?f=99&t=7006) for this error, but when i change OPENGL to OPENGL-ES nothing change.

what can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a same problem, i followed step of [this page](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/) and i could installed opencv correctly in raspberry.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved it. I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS LXDE on raspberry pi.
I don't know the exact core library which causes this issue (other than the one mentioned in error), So this approach might be a little generic. (when all else fails).

1. Make sure you have a fresh copy of opencv and opencv_contrib objects.
2. `git checkout --force 3.3.1` (please check where the head is at in your download by running `git log` or on the github page)
3. create a build folder and make sure you have all the dependency libraries. This is tricky since some of them are visual. Examples include : `libgstreame1.0-base-dev`.
4. Use 
   `cmake CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \`

`CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \`

`INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \`

`INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \`

`WITH_TBB=ON \`

`WITH_V4L=ON \`

`WITH_QT=ON \`

`WITH_OPENGL=ON \`

`OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \`

If this doesn't work you can add `-D` symbol at the beginning of every line after `cmake` command.
You must add a variable if you want to use cuda (if you have a graphics card with appropriate drivers) by adding `USE_CUDA=ON` in the above command.

For more help please refer [this](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv3-on-ubuntu/) and [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/) .

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I come across the same problem with U on raspi 3b.

Maybe [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/16506/commits/f05d5888c9c37302e0a0eebf7e7eca65017ebf5f) will solve this bug.

> `Do not include glx.h when using GLES`.

> GL/glx.h is included on all LINUX plattforms, which is wrong for a number of reasons:
>
> - GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT is defined in GL/gl.h, so we
>   want gl.h not glx.h, the latter just includes the former.
> - GL/gl.h is a Desktop GL header, and should not be included
>   on GLES plattforms.
> - GL/gl.h is already included via QtOpenGL -> QtGui/qopengl.h on desktop plattforms.
> - This fixes a problem when Qt is compiled with GLES, which is often done on ARM platforms where desktop GL is not or only poorly supported (e.g. slow due to emulation).

```cpp
//modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp::54
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

//Get GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT definition, not available in GLES 2 or
//OpenGL 3 core profile or later
#ifdef HAVE_QT_OPENGL
//    #if defined Q_WS_X11 /* Qt4 */ || defined Q_OS_LINUX /* Qt5 */
//        #include <GL/glx.h>
    #if defined Q_WS_X11 /* Qt4 */ || \
            (!defined(QT_OPENGL_ES_2) && defined Q_OS_LINUX) /* Qt5 with desktop OpenGL */
        #include <GL/gl.h>
    #endif
#endif
    
//modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp::3226
//void OpenGlViewPort::updateGl()

void OpenGlViewPort::initializeGL() {
#ifdef GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
#endif
}

void OpenGlViewPort::resizeGL(int w, int h)
```